# jQuery Plugin that does this?

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, annotate

[image]

Is there a jQuery plugin that allows this?

Comment: Moar wordz plz to describe what this does (but nice sketch)

Comment: From the sketch, I think the plugin would add numbers to the image, detect onhover for those numbers, and then highlight the corresponding list element on the right

Comment: Do you want that text on the right (#1 to circle 1, etc) to display below the cursor when you hover?

Comment: Why not use a map and area tag ([ref](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp)) with a tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a "tag" plugin to do something similar?

http://www.jpictag.com/demos/edition

Or

http://djpate.com/2011/01/14/jtag-a-jquery-plugin-to-tag-pictures-more/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at quite a bit of effort (and cpu power and thought) for very little gain. It essentially involves creating your own bit of javascript / jquery plugin.

But if you still wanted to go about doing it, you're going to need to load an image onto a canvas element, pull in its data using getImageData, and then use some pretty advanced OCR trickery to figure out where & what these letters are.

It's definitely possible if you've got the time - [John Resig analyses a Greasemonkey script that used this technique (along with Neural Networks) to solve captchas here](http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/).